# « Les airs que j’ai entendu/entendus... » ?

Tags: grammaire, accord, participe-passé

I can't figure out why here in my first sentence le participe passé agrees with *les violonistes*, but in the second it doesn't agree with *les airs*. 
I thought it should agree in both cases, since the COD is placed before the verb. What am I not seeing?

> 1) Les violonistes que j'ai entendu**s** jouer sont habiles.
>
> 2) Les airs que j'ai entendu jouer étaient mélancoliques.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a tricky one:  the past participle doesn't agree in the second sentence because the complement isn't doing the action defined by the infinitive. For example, following the same principle, you should write:

> Les pièces (de théâtre) que j'ai vu jouer

And NOT

> Les pièces que j'ai vues jouer

[Reference](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.projet-voltaire.fr/regles-orthographe/les-enfants-que-j-ai-entendu-crier-les-enfants-que-j-ai-entendus-crier/&ved=2ahUKEwi_ju2DqLfiAhXJZlAKHccPAZMQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1XCzdf9dwSzda3euY5mTRW&cshid=1558809121533)

Comment: @LPH thanks for fixing my English :-) I knew something was wrong as I was writing it but couldn't put my finger on it :-)

Comment: As far as the principle goes it's perfect, resolved; when it comes to the syntax I'm less sure this type of sentence is quite legitimate. There is no problem when a subject for the infinitive is added: "Les airs que j'ai entendu les musiciens jouer étaient mélancoliques."; there is no doubt that the COD is "musician" or from another point of view the infinitive clause. However, when that COD/SUJET is removed, there is a transitive verb without an object (voir) and you might be groping for one (that leading you to "que") and no subject for the infinitive; all of that is very disturbing.